# Adding bootstrap template to jsp

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to add a free layout template to my webapp, but something goes wrong.

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoRUj.png)

Here's head of my index.jsp file:

```
<head>
  <title>Bicycleshop Bootstarp Website Template | Home :: w3layouts</title>
  <link href="WEB-INF/template/css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="/WEB-INF/template/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom Theme files -->
  <link href="/WEB-INF/template/css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <!-- Custom Theme files -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Doppio+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

I included this line in dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/template/**" location="/WEB-INF/"/>
```

Template is in directory /WEB-INF/template/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out I have added bad location path. This one is proper for my structure:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/template/**" location="/WEB-INF/template/"/>
```

Now it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can't have your static resources inside WEB-INF or a sub-directory of WEB-INF. This directory is not served by the app server. It is kind of protected area. You can serve the data if you add some kind of (code) proxy serving it for you, like when a Servlet defaults display to a JSP stored inside WEB-INF.

What you meant by

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/template/**" location="/WEB-INF/"/>:
```

is all the URLs that match `/template/**` are to be served from `/WEB-INF`, thus, the URLs you specified in the JSP, starting by `/WEB-INF/template` will have Spring look inside `/WEB-INF/WEB-INF`, so remove the `/WEB-INF` from all the URLs inside the JSP.

Then for Spring to proxy your resources, You need to use JSTL or Spring Taglib or `pageContext` like so:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/template/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Or:

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/template/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Edit**

With full source code:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

mvc-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="demo.spring.mvc" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/" />

    <mvc:view-resolvers>
        <mvc:jsp prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" suffix=".jsp" />
    </mvc:view-resolvers>

</beans>
```

Welcome.java

```
package demo.spring.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class Welcome {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Welcome";
    }

}
```

/WEB-INF/views/Welcome.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/default.css" />" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="alert">This should appear in red!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

/WEB-INF/static/css/default.css

```
.alert {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I've edited with full the code I tested. Pay attention to the url mapping of the dispatcher servlet. I could make this example work with a mapping of `/mvc/*` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference seems incomplete as you have the CSS file (of bootstrap, but not a theme) and are missing the Bootstrap JS file.

Also, try loading from a CDN.
https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/